# Что является основной целью для классов-потомков от TestCase?

Tags: python, юнит-тесты

Суть моего вопроса в том чтобы попытаться разобраться и уяснить для себя для достижения какой цели пишутся потомки базового класса TestCase(к примеру от [TestCase из docs.python.org](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase))? Подобный TestCase-e класс, также встречается и в других библиотеках, к примеру: в jUnit, nUnit и др.

Для более предметного обсуждением возьмем какой-либо пример кода в котором существует несколько функциональностей. Предположим есть модуль *views.py* входящий в Blueprint *auth*. Напомнию что Blueprint это термин из мира микрофрейморка Flask-a. В этом примере несколько функциональностей: смена пароля, получение токена, добавление и удаление пользователя.

Вот код этого *views.py* модуля:

```
@auth.route('/users/register', methods=['POST'])
@administrator_required
def register_user():
    pass

@auth.route('/users/unregister', methods=['DELETE'])
@administrator_required
def unregister_user():
    pass

@auth.route('/users/change-password', methods=['PUT'])
def change_password():
    pass

@auth.route('/users/token')
@credentials_required
def generate_token():
    pass
```

Повторюсь, это всего-лишь пример куска кода в котором несколько функциональностей. Можно было бы также привести и математический класс, где тоже несколько возможностей: сложение по модулю, вычисление энтропии и др.

Как нужно писать модульные тесты для покрытия проверками тестируемого кода в котором несколько функциональностей. К пимеру для этого Blueprint-a ? Какой набор тестов должен содержать такой тестовый класс(потомок от TestCase)?

1. Может быть набор тестов должен покрывать весь компонент\blueprint ?
2. Возможно нужно набор тестов покрывает только одну функциональность. Таким образом появляется несколько тестовых классов : TokenTest, RegisterUserTest, UnregisterUserTest, ChangePasswordTest ?
3. Или же надо писать набор тестов для одного метода\функции являющегося частью реализации тестируемой функциональности ?

*UPD*:

Мой вопрос заключает не в "Как использовать Flask?" и не в "Как написать модульный тест для Flask-приложения?. Повторюсь еще раз, кусок из Flask-приложения приведен только лишь для примера, потому что мне сложно рассуждать абстрактно и лучше всего предметно с приведением любого куска кода.

Comment: заголовок и тело вопроса не соответствуют друг другу: можно использовать TestCase подклассы не упоминая flask, и наоборот можно тестировать flask-функции, не создавая явно TestCase подклассы. Лучше на два вопроса разбить или оставить только тот вопрос, на который действительно хочется получить ответ.

Comment: Почему не соответствуют? В чем именно это выражается? Как раз-таки прослеживается цель выяснить какие тесты должны содержаться в потомках Test-Case-a? Другими словами, какая у него цель?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если говорить строго, то:

- Один тест - это не класс, а один метод `test_*` (т.е. именно тот кусок кода, который тестирует выбранную feature). Класс, таким образом - это просто объединение нескольких тестов.
- Наследование от конкретного класса необязательно и может быть внесено как требование только конкретным фреймворком тестирования. Фреймоврку же это нужно для предоставления общего функционала - before/after хуки, дата провайдеры, произвольные имена тестов и прочее.

> Как тестировать этот blueprint

Никак. Можно тестировать отдельные функции, входящие в этот blueprint, но сама организация и работоспособность этого blueprint лежит на flask, и поэтому его тестировать не нужно. Можно тестировать *приложение в целом* - написать прямо по ТЗ/SRS тесты, которые проверяют соответствие исполнения задумке, и тогда они будут организовываться в виде сценариев, проверяющих аспект приложения.

> Какой набор тестов должен содержать такой тестовый класс (потомок от TestCase)?

В случае модульного тестирования принято покрывать один класс одним tests case'ом. В случае тестирования более высокого уровня обычно берется один *аспект* - например, проверка скачивания файлов - и туда пишутся все тесты, которые этот аспект проверяют. В случае, если их получается слишком много - подразделяют по функционалу. В общем, никаких четких установок нет; главное, чтобы один test case целиком вбирал в себя ту сферу функционала, на которую нацелен: один класс - собираются все тесты по этому классу, система сессий - проверяет всю работу с сессиями, проверка авторизации - все сценарии, возможные при авторизации. Если есть авторизация через большое количество провайдеров - по кейсу на каждого из провайдеров. В идеале, конечно, всё должно быть максимально атомарным (и тогда каждый test case состоял бы из одного теста), но это требует слишком больших усилий.

Конкретный выбор из трех предложенных вариантов зависит от фреймворка и методологии. Писать различные сценарии - это BDD, и, на мой взгляд, самое разумное решение на системном уровне тестирования; выбор между первым и третьим зависит от количества кода в тестах.

Comment: Я правильно понял, 1) что тестовый фреймворк позволяет организовать тестирование не только модульное, но и интеграционное? 2) И если да, то значит первый вопрос перед написанием теста это : какой тип теста мы собираемся писать: модульный или интеграционный?

Comment: Что позволяет фреймворк - зависит от фреймворка. В системном тестировании простые ассерты не очень применимы, и иногда требуется продолжать сценарий, даже несмотря на завал условия. По второму вопросу - в общем да, сначала разобраться, что требуется оттестировать, затем это реализовывать.

Answer (score 2):

> Что является основной целью для классов-потомков от TestCase?

Потомок [TestCase](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#organizing-test-code) может группировать несколько связанных (тематически) тестов (`test*()` методы), их общую настройку (`setUp()` метод -- исполняется перед каждым `test*()` методом) и завершение (`tearDown()` метод -- исполняется после каждого теста) и предоставляет множество удобных методов (`assertEqual()`, `assertRaises()`, etc методы), которые помогают писать сами отдельные тесты-компонент.

> Как нужно писать модульные тесты для покрытия этого Blueprint-a ?

Blueprint по сути является веб-приложением, рассчитанным на повторное использование. Поэтому [тестировать blueprint можно также как обычное приложение](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/testing/#the-first-test):

```
class FlaskrTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.db_fd, flaskr.app.config['DATABASE'] = tempfile.mkstemp()
        self.app = flaskr.app.test_client()
        flaskr.init_db()

    def tearDown(self):
        os.close(self.db_fd)
        os.unlink(flaskr.app.config['DATABASE'])

    def test_empty_db(self):
        rv = self.app.get('/')
        assert 'No entries here so far' in rv.data
```

Основным здесь является `test_client()` и соответствующие запросы (`.get('/')` в примере).

> Что означает "тематически связанных" ? Может быть одну функцию тестируют? А может быть один класс? А может быть одну функциональность?

@sys_dev: это может означать всё что автор тестов захочет т.е., не обязательно следовать функциям, классам, "функциональности".

Формально это все тесты, которые имеют общие setUp/tearDown методы и объединённые под одним именем (имя подкласса -- если тяжело имя придумать, то это указывает, что тесты плохо связаны).

Comment: Прошу прощения, но пока не понятно. Что означают Ваши "тематически связанных" ? Может быть одну функцию тестируют? А может быть один класс? А может быть одну функциональность? Другими словами, мне хочется знать что является критерием связности?

Comment: @sys_dev: обновил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо! Обновил свой вопрос. Мой вопрос связан не с использованием Flask-a. Заключается в стратегии и способах организации кода модульных тестах при написании потомков от базовых классов. Ведь подобные TestCase из Python-библиотеки также встречаются и в других языках программирования, к примеру в jUnit

Comment: @sys_dev: это тема для целой книги (или несколько). Вот [список книг по unit testing для примера](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3923471/4279)

Comment: Обновил еще раз свой вопрос. Да, согласен с Вами и книги читаю, к примеру сейчас "Art of Unit Testing", но! Ни в одной еще не увидел ясного и четкого пояснения моего вопроса ;(

Comment: @sys_dev: глубокого смысла тут нет. Есть технические ограничения, которые я упомянул в ответе, а дальше каждый волен использовать `TestCase` в соответствии с личной/корпоративной философией тестирования (кто-то может ответить с изложением их личной  (субъективной) текущей философии). Чтобы получить более детальный ответ, необходимо конкретный (более специфичный) вопрос задать о  реальном коде и реальной проблеме, которую необходимо решить.